# What is the propability of pulling 4 specific letters at once from an 8th letter word(without duplicate letters)?

Tags: probability

Lets say I have the letters `['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i']`. What is the probability of me pulling out `['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']` at once.

I know that the probability is `1/2`, however, I am struggling to understand why? The reasoning I was given is "Since there are 4 letters out of 8 and you are pulling them at once the result is `1/2`".

I even tried to manually try the 'experiment' and pulled `['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']` only once out of more than 20 times

EDIT:
**The order doesn't matter**

Comment: to pull out "qwer" in order ? or order does not matter ?

Comment: order doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am confused about the original question, the probability is not one-half.

As I read the question, you have an 8-letter word, and you want to know the probability of pulling a specific set of 4 letters out of that 8-letter word.  Alternatively, I think of 8 unique Scrabble tiles, putting them in a bag, reaching my hand in and drawing out 4 of them all at once; what are the odds that I get a specific set of 4?

This relates to how many orderings there are of the original 8 letters.  In combinatorics, the "choose" function counts the number of ways that a subset of length $r$ can be obtained from a set of length $n$, without regard to order and without replacement (i.e., the Scrabble bag scenario).  It is denoted as either $C(n;r)$ or $\binom{n}{r}$, which has a formula $$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$In your case, there are a total of $\binom{8}{4}$ ways to select 4 tiles out of a bag of 8, without replacement, and without regard to ordering.  Doing the math, there are 70 ways of this happening.

Since you are looking for one specific combination, it's the inverse of this, or 1/70.

(For the intuition on the choose function, let's pick your 4 tiles first.  There are 8 ways to choose the first tile, 7 ways to choose the second, 6 for the third and 5 for the fourth.  This is a total of 8*7*6*5 combinations for picking your four tiles, but there's a problem: this gives a separate counting for each order of how you chose the tiles; so "abcd" and "bcda" are two separate orderings.

(To eliminate double counting, we divide out the ways in which each of those tiles can be arranged: 4 ways to pick the placement of the first tile, 3 ways for the second, ... for a total of 4*3*2*1.  Thus, the answer we are looking for is 8*7*6*5/4*3*2*1.

(Now, we get factorials out of that by simply doing algebra.  Note that the numerator is 8!/4! - the 1*2*3*4 cancels each other out.  The denominator is already 4!, so we get the result of $\frac{8!}{4!4!}$, which is an instance of the general form,$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$)

Answer (score 1):

There are $8*7*6*5/(4*3*2*1) = 70$ equally likely combinations of 4 letters from 8. Only one of those is your specified combination. So the probability is $1/70$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order does not matter, that's the same as pulling out $4$ black balls from an urn containing $4$ black + $4$ white balls.
There are  $\binom{8}{4}=70$ ways to arrange the eight balls in line.  Only one of these will have the first four black.